# JAVA code in Android Studio not executing if statement

Tags: android, if-statement, logic

I am having a hard time in trying to figure out why the if statements in the following code are not executing properly:

```
double yint = -157.42;
if(copy_denominator.contains("x^"+nextBottom))yint = -1*constant / d2;

Log.d(PERIOD,"copy den: "+copy_denominator +" yint "+yint);
//the Log statement above prints out that yint = 3.0;

if(yint != -157.42)
Log.d(PERIOD,"oblique 5 "+slope+"x + "+yint);//I expect this to print to Log

if(yint == -157.42)Log.d(PERIOD,"oblique 6 "+slope+"x ");//This prints out.
```

I don't know why the statement: if(yint != -157.42) does not execute. 
I have never seen this before, could it be a bug in Android Studio.

thanks for any advice

Comment: Your code formatting is very bad. Also using == and != to compare to constants with floating point is not a good idea. Rather allow for some margin of error when comparing. Furthermore don't name a variable of type double "yint". Also are you sure that it prints out "yint = 3.0;"? Hope this helps. Good luck getting an answer to your question.

Comment: I think you might be correct. Let me see how can I try this margin of error calculation. @user643011

Comment: yes it prints out "yint = 3.0" @user643011 . I try to correct by setting yint = 157.42 and using  if(Math.abs(157.42 - yint) > 0.001)  , but it is still not executing!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if(Math.abs(-157.42 - yint) > 0.001)` ? Please edit the original question to reflect the new code and also please format the code for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very strange question. You can post more code snapshots about the context. The following is my context snapshot. Hope help others and you:

> Android Studio 2.3.3
>
> compileSdkVersion 25
>
> buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
>
> minSdkVersion 16
>
> targetSdkVersion 25

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String PERIOD = "PERIOD";

    private ArrayList<String> copy_denominator = new ArrayList<>();
    private int nextBottom = 2;
    private final double constant = 6.0D;
    private double d2 = 2.0D;
    private String slope = "2.3";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        copy_denominator.add("x^2");

        double yint = -157.42;
        if (copy_denominator.contains("x^" + nextBottom)) yint = -1 * constant / d2;

        Log.d(PERIOD, "copy den: " + copy_denominator + " yint " + yint);
        //the Log statement above prints out that yint = 3.0;

        if (yint != -157.42)
            Log.d(PERIOD, "oblique 5 " + slope + "x + " + yint);//I expect this to print to Log

        if (yint == -157.42) Log.d(PERIOD, "oblique 6 " + slope + "x ");//This prints out.

    }
}
```

The log are alright:

```
[Logcat prints][1]
```

The log:

```
08-09 19:49:21.792 12323-12323/io.github.dkbai.appdemo D/PERIOD: copy den: [x^2] yint -3.0

08-09 19:49:21.792 12323-12323/io.github.dkbai.appdemo D/PERIOD: oblique 5 2.3x + -3.0
```